# Replace "-" "dash" using regular expression in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have an img tag like this

```
img alt="Fresh-Frozen-Plasma-Style-Good">
```

Is it possible to replace "-" characters with spaces using regular expression in Dreamweaver, so the result is like this:

`img alt="Fresh Frozen Plasma Style Good">` ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have access to Dreamweaver to test, but I think it uses a fairly industry generic syntax/flavor, so try:

replace: `img\s+alt="([^"-]+)-([^"-]+)"`

with:   (a single space)

### Edit, after a long time

The above find replace expression would have to be run multiple times (each run would find and replace the first dash it found)

an alternative might be something like the following, if lookahead and capturing groups are again supported like "normal" or industry generic syntax these days. First, ensure that there is a space at the end of the sample or somewhere after the hyphen, then find

```
-(?=.*?( ))
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

or maybe `$1`?

This will find and match a hyphen that is followed by some characters and a space. It will capture that space, and use it to replace the hyphen that was matched. This will work with a single "global" find and replace, but won't be restricted to only inside img tags

Maybe if a product or language supports variable length look behind (not common still, but *maybe?*) then you could do something similar to the following:

```
(?<=img\s*=\s*"[^"-]*)-(?=.*?( ))
```

Comment: In img tag, there can be many words, so what would be the expression and how to replace

Comment: very recent down vote... interesting... wonder why someone would come along and feel this was unhelpful enough to downvote after all this time